# rails fixtures relation does not exist when using STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i have something like

```
class User < AR
end

class SuperUser < User
  has_one :profile, class_name: "SuperUser::Profile"
end

class SuperUser::Profile < AR
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'super_user_'
  end

  belongs_to :super_user
end
```

and in my fixtures

```
|- super_user
  |- profiles.yml
|- users.yml
```

I get this error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "user_profiles" does not exist
```

any idea why the fixture is looking for table `user_profiles` instead of the correct one called `super_user_profiles`?

EDIT:
If i change `SuperUser::Profile` class to `Super::Profile` (and has_one and fixture folder name to match) it all works...

Comment: please post your schema, you may need to define `foreign_key` as its inferring a user that has_one profile is user_profiles.

Comment: doesn't seem to be the key the issue, i tried setting it with the same result. See my edit above. Other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Did you properly name and create folders & files for your subclassed models?